# ImportError: No module named yaml - but I have yaml

Tags: python, ros, robotics, gazebo-simu

The logical answer, if I don't have a specific module is to just install it. `pip install pyyaml` but I have installed it, and this just spits back "`Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages (5.3.1)`".

I got this issue while setting up Baxter for Gazebo.

PLUS INFO: I can import it for any other project, except this.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: make sure you are using the correct pip. I don't know Baxter, but if it comes with its own Python installation you might need to find its pip and run that pip (e.g. `/my/path/to/baxter/bin/pip install pyyaml`

Comment: I'm not using Virtual env, and Baxter doesn't have its own pip.